# Image drawing complex analysis

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$w=u+iv,z=x+iy$ are complex numbers and we have $w=z^2-2z$. Determine the image in the $w$-plane of the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$.

I have tried to answer this here [Question and Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJs7W.png). I have problems drawing the image and have no idea on how to do this using Matlab, since I know only basic functions on Matlab.
I need someone to also check my attached attempted answer to see if I am on the correct track. I also need help with drawing the image.

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please take the tour http://math.stackexchange.com/tour and learn how to format math for this site http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation People here dislike questions where they have to look at a link to see what it is about, so I have edited you question for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, Almagest, I am still new on this site. I appreciate that you edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to note that the general point on the unit circle is $x=\cos t,y=\sin t$. So we get $u=\cos^2t-2\cos t-\sin^2t,v=2\cos t\sin t-2\sin t$. That is the parametric equation for the curve in the $w$-plane. I am not familiar with MatLab but I am sure it will have a function for parametric plots. Using Mathematica we have.

[image]

Comment: wow, thank you very much. I did not think of this way using parametric plots. But is my logic for question 1.2 correct as I was trying to solve for the radius?